# How to correctly create a new account in MediaWiki using Python?

Tags: python, mediawiki

As part of a platform I'm working with, I need to be able to create new Wiki users in a MediaWiki (v1.27.1) based site via a Python script.  I'm currently working with the following test code:

```
payload = {'action': 'query', 'format': 'json', 'meta': 'tokens', 'type': 'createaccount'}
r1 = requests.post(baseurl + 'api.php', data=payload)
createaccount_token = r1.json()['query']['tokens']['createaccounttoken']
payload = {
    'action': 'createaccount', 
    'format': 'json', 
    'name': 'test', 
    'email': 'test@test.com', 
    'realname': 'Test User',
    'password': 'TestTest123',
    'retype': 'TestTest123',
    'reason': 'Testing Python',
    'language': 'en',
    'createtoken': createaccount_token
}
r2 = requests.post(baseurl + 'api.php', data=payload)
```

However, this code is returning an 'Invalid token' error.

I've tried urlencoding the token (even though this shouldn't be required any more) but it didn't make a difference.

Can anyone give me any pointers, please?

Comment: Tokens are stored in the session. You should use `requests.Session` or `cookielib.CookieJar` or some similar way of persisting the session.

Comment: (FWIW urlencoding the token *is* required, but the `requests` library should take care of that.)

Comment: Are even the create account tokens stored in sessions?  The MediaWiki API seems to suggest that tokens are handled differently when creating new accounts, as tokens are a single use affair, apparently.

Comment: Sure. What would be the point of having a token, otherwise?